Navigation to list view
Am trying to navigate to custom list view from lwc button.
Here my code :
HTML :
<footer class="slds-card__footer">
    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Finish" title="Finish" onclick={handleFinish}></lightning-button>
</footer>

JavaScript:
    import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
export default class DownloadNote extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement){
    
    handleFinish() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: 'Note__c',
                actionName: 'list'
            },
            state: {
                filterName: 'Verified Note'
            }
        });
    }
}


And? Please edit your question to include more detail about where you’re stuck and narrow your question down to an actual problem

For custom list views, you need to use the 18-character unique ID of the list view instead of its name.
Look at the URL in your browser. The 18-character ID of the list view will be part of the URL. It usually looks something like this: https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/00BT0000002TONQMA4.
Updated JavaScript Code
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class DownloadNote extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

        handleFinish() {
                this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                        type: 'standard__objectPage',
                        attributes: {
                                objectApiName: 'Note__c',
                                actionName: 'list'
                        },
                        state: {
                                filterName: '00BT0000002TONQMA4' // Replace with your actual list view ID
                        }
                });
        }
}

HTML:
<footer class="slds-card__footer">
    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Finish" title="Finish" onclick={handleFinish}></lightning-button>
</footer>

Update(11/09/2024):
Yes, you can dynamically retrieve the list view ID by querying it based on the list view name and object type.
Apex Controller:
public class ListViewController {
        @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
        public static String getListViewId(String objectApiName, String listViewName) {
                ListView listView = [SELECT Id FROM ListView WHERE SObjectType = :objectApiName AND Name = :listViewName LIMIT 1];
                return listView.Id;
        }
}

JS:
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import getListViewId from '@salesforce/apex/ListViewController.getListViewId';

export default class DownloadNote extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
        listViewId;

        @wire(getListViewId, { objectApiName: 'Note__c', listViewName: 'All_Notes' })
        wiredListView({ error, data }) {
                if (data) {
                        this.listViewId = data;
                } else if (error) {
                        console.error('Error fetching list view ID:', error);
                }
        }

        handleFinish() {
                if (this.listViewId) {
                        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                                type: 'standard__objectPage',
                                attributes: {
                                        objectApiName: 'Note__c',
                                        actionName: 'list'
                                },
                                state: {
                                        filterName: this.listViewId
                                }
                        });
                } else {
                        console.error('List view ID not available');
                }
        }
}

HTML:
<footer class="slds-card__footer">
        <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Finish" title="Finish" onclick={handleFinish}></lightning-button>
</footer>


Is there any way to pass the list view instead of id. Like dynamically get ID by query?

@kjSkill, Check the updated section.
